# Python/Plone: Getting all keywords and showing for EDIT content is very slow

Tags: performance, plone, keyword, plone-4.x, slowdown

Python/Plone: Getting all keywords and showing for EDIT content is very slow (keywords.pt)
No of keywords is 20000 so traversing these huge no of keywords is taking one minute.

Keywords which no has grown large is taking time....any solution is welcomed

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
i18n:domain="plone">
<head><title></title></head>
<body>

    <!-- Keyword Widgets -->

    <metal:view_macro define-macro="view"
            tal:define="kssClassesView context/@@kss_field_decorator_view;
                        getKssClasses nocall:kssClassesView/getKssClassesInlineEditable;">
        <div metal:define-macro="keyword-field-view"
            tal:define="kss_class python:getKssClasses(fieldName,
                              templateId='widgets/keyword', macro='keyword-field-view');
                              uid context/UID|nothing"
            tal:attributes="class kss_class;
                            id string:parent-fieldname-$fieldName-$uid">
            <ul metal:define-slot="inside">
                <li tal:repeat="item accessor"
                    tal:content="item"/>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </metal:view_macro>

    <metal:define define-macro="edit">
        <metal:use use-macro="field_macro | context/widgets/field/macros/edit">
            <tal:define metal:fill-slot="widget_body" define="contentKeywords accessor;
                    allowedKeywords python: context.collectKeywords(fieldName, field.accessor, widget.vocab_source);
                    site_props context/portal_properties/site_properties|nothing;
                    format widget/format | string:select;
                    allowRolesToAddKeywords site_props/allowRolesToAddKeywords|nothing;">

                <div tal:condition="allowedKeywords" id="existingTagsSection">
                    <tal:comment tal:replace="nothing">
                        dl semantically associates selector name with values
                    </tal:comment>
                    <dl id="existingTags">
                        <label for="subject">
                            <dt id="existingTagsTitle">uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
                                <span i18n:translate="label_select_existing_tags">
                                    Select from existing tags. 
                                </span>
                            </dt>
                            <span id="existingTagsHelp" class="formHelp" i18n:translate="label_existingTagsHelp">
                                Use Control/Command/Shift keys to select multiple tags.
                            </span>
                            <tal:comment tal:replace="nothing">
                                Type-to-skip functionality with javascript enabled 
                                could be described as 
                                "Hover and type the first letter to skip through tags." 
                                However, on touch-driven devices, vertical hover typically 
                                scrolls the page, so horizontal hover is necessary to enable this.  
                                Alternatively, clicking any of the tags also enables type-to-skip.  
                                So the help could technically be extended to handle this special case 
                                as "Hover or click and type the first letter to skip through tags.", 
                                but I think this would be confusing to the majority of users.
                                The decision at this point is to not try to explain any of this on the page.
                            </tal:comment>
                        </label>
                        <div class="visualClear"><!-- --></div>
                        <select id="predefined_subjects"
                            name="predefined_subjects:list"
                            size="14"
                            multiple="multiple"
                            tal:condition="python:format!='checkbox'"
                            tal:attributes="id string:${fieldName};
                                            name string:${fieldName}_existing_keywords:list;">
                            <option value="#" tal:repeat="keyword allowedKeywords"
                                tal:content="keyword" tal:attributes="value keyword;
                                selected python:test(context.unicodeTestIn(keyword, value), 'selected', None)">
                                An existing tag
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <tal:comment tal:replace="nothing">
                            These spans are hidden by css, and used by the JavaScript called below.
                        </tal:comment>
                        <span id="noTagsSelected" i18n:translate="label_noTagsSelected">No tags currently selected.</span>
                        <span id="oneOrMoreTagsSelected" i18n:translate="label_oneOrMoreTagsSelected">% tags currently selected.</span>
                        <tal:comment tal:replace="nothing">
                            Call js to modify this widget with both a scrollbar and checkboxes.
                            There may be a better place to put this js call; 
                            examples exist in others' widget.py and js files,
                            but having it here covers cases where some but not all select elements 
                            call js to be modified.
                            Todo: The #subject should eventually refer to the template variable.
                        </tal:comment>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            jq(document).ready( function() {
                                jq("#subject").multiSelect();
                            });
                        </script>
                        <input type="hidden"
                               value=""
                               tal:condition="not:field/required | nothing"
                               tal:attributes="name string:${fieldName}_existing_keywords:default:list" />
                        <tal:loop tal:repeat="keyword allowedKeywords"
                                  tal:condition="python:format=='checkbox'">
                            <div class="ArchetypesKeywordValue" id=""
                                 tal:attributes="id string:archetypes-value-${fieldName}_${repeat/keyword/number}">
                                <input class="blurrable"
                                    tal:attributes="
                                        type string:checkbox;
                                        name string:${fieldName}_existing_keywords:list;
                                        id string:${fieldName}_${repeat/keyword/number};
                                        checked python:test(context.unicodeTestIn(keyword, value), 'checked', None);
                                        value keyword" />
                                <label 
                                    tal:content="keyword"
                                    tal:attributes="for string:${fieldName}_${repeat/keyword/number}">
                                    An existing tag
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </tal:loop>
                    </dl>
                    <dl id="selectedTagsSection">
                        <dt id="selectedTagsHeading" class="formHelp"></dt>
                        <dd id="selectedTags"></dd>
                    </dl>
                    <div class="visualClear"><!-- --></div>
                </div>

              <!--  <tal:condition condition="python:not widget.roleBasedAdd or (allowRolesToAddKeywords and [role for role in user.getRolesInContext(context) if role in allowRolesToAddKeywords])">-->
                    <dl id="newTagsSection">
                        <label for="subject_keywords">
                            <dt id="newTagsTitle">
                                <span i18n:translate="label_create_new_tags">
                                    Create and apply new tags. 
                                </span>
                            </dt>
                            <span id="newTagsHelp" i18n:translate="label_newTagsHelp" class="formHelp">
                                Enter one tag per line, multiple words allowed.
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        <dd id="newTags">
                            <textarea 
                                id="entered_subjects"
                                name="subject:lines"
                                rows="4"
                                tal:attributes="id string:${fieldName}_keywords;
                                                name string:${fieldName}_keywords:lines;"
                                tal:define="subject python:[item for item in value if not context.unicodeTestIn(item,allowedKeywords)]"
                                tal:content="python:'\n'.join(subject)">
                                A new tag
                            </textarea>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
               <!-- </tal:condition>-->

            </tal:define>
        </metal:use>
    </metal:define>

    <div metal:define-macro="search">
      <div metal:use-macro="context/widgets/keyword/macros/edit">
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear is a know issue of the old Plone 4 keyword widget.

You should probably change the widget.

- An add-on like [eea.tags](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/eea.tags) should help.
- You can also try to use Plone 5 widget from plone.app.widgets, but this probably it's a more complex task (and not without side effects).

Comment: Thanks @Luca Its works perfectly for plone  4.3 and plus

Comment: @piyush3527236 what exactly works? You used eea.tags or p.a.widgets?

Comment: eea.tags ........ Its works perfectly for plone  4.3 and plus..........for version < 4.3 update plone.app.jquery = 1.4.4   to 1.8.3 as eea.tags does not support jquery 1.4.4 and plone version < 4.3 does not support jquery 1.7.2